# Adding QWidget into QGridLayout adds border to layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Currently I have my program organized this way in QTDesigner (which I use with VS 2022): QMainWindow->centralWidget(QWidget)->QTabWidget->Tab(QWidget)->QGridLayout.
All these elements are created in QtDesigner.
In my cpp code I'm downloading some data and generating QTableWidget* m_table.
Unfortunately after adding it to QGridLayout element, I get a black border exactly around this layout. How it's possible if it border can't be set at all for this element, at least in QtDesigner?

```
QTableWidget* m_table;
///(...)
ui.gridLayout->addWidget(m_table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `Qt's` stylesheets. You should be able to style your `QTableWidget` in any way you want to.

Keep in mind a `QTableWidget` is specialized version of `QTableView`, so you have set your stylesheet to a `QTableView`:

```
m_table->setStyleSheet("QTableView {background: transparent; border: 1px solid green;}");
```

Here are some links to get you started with `Qt` stylesheets:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: Mate thanks a lot! So it looks it was QTableWidget border which fitted QGridLayout border. I've set m_table border to 0px and now it works like I wanted to. Cheers!